# Any evidence of Ram Temple in Ayodhya being destroyed before Babri Masjid?

Tags: history, temple, rama, india, ayodhya

I am looking for clarity on the case, argument or evidence of destruction (non-existence) of the Ram temple in Ayodhya before the Babri Masjid.

That is, is there any source that talks about the temple before the destruction happened in the early 16<sup>th</sup> century (1528 AD, I believe)?

Note: **There is sufficient evidence that a temple existed in the mosque site, but is there any direct evidence that the temple was actually destroyed to build the mosque there?**

Also, Wikipedia [states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ram_Janmabhoomi):

> The Ramayana states that the location of Rama's birthplace is on the banks of the Sarayu river in the city of Ayodhya. A section of Hindus claim that the exact site of Rama's birthplace is where the Babri Masjid once stood in the present-day Ayodhya, Uttar Pradesh. According to this theory, the Mughals demolished a Hindu shrine that marked the spot, and constructed a mosque in its place. People opposed to this theory state that such claims arose only in the 18<sup>th</sup> century, and that there is no evidence for the spot being the birthplace of Rama.
>
> .... Since then, the archaeological excavations have indicated the presence of a temple beneath the mosque rubble, **but whether the structure was a Rama shrine (or a temple at all) remains disputed**.

---

**EDIT**:

This question is **not** a duplicate of the generic question *[Was there a Rama Temple in Ayodhya?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9351)* (there can be many temples of Rama in Ayodhya!)

In this question, I'm specifically looking for evidence that proves there once stood a Temple of Rama in Ayodhya that was demolished to build the Babri Masjid.

Also, I don't understand why people are downvoting my question. My intention is not to offend anyone, I'm merely seeking credible information here. Thanks.

Comment: See [Was there Rama Temple in Ayodhya?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9351/3500)

Comment: @learningbrain Questions relating to Temples are not off-topic.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I want to know whether there is evidence for Ram temple destruction and building Babri Masjid on top of it, not for the  existence of Ram temple per se!

Comment: @Naveen I think your question is very similar to the [other one](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9351/2995) which is why people are voting to close this one as a duplicate, so, I've made some edits to your question to prevent closure.

Comment: @Naveen before the edit, the question seemed to be a duplicate. Now your edit made the question clear. Retracted the close vote.

Comment: @Naveen I think other (marked) question meant Rama Janmabhoomi. OP's [comment](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9351/was-there-a-rama-temple-in-ayodhya#comment21157_9351) says the same.

Comment: @sv. This question is duplicate of other question. See OPs comment.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Ok maybe, I missed that comment earlier, but OP there needs to add that to the question as right now it looks like a very generic question.