# Is Ayodhya mentioned as a major Tirth-Sthal(pilgrimage site) in any scripture?

Tags: rama

Is Ayodhya mentioned as a major pilgrimage site in any scripture ?

Comment: [Related](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9351/was-there-a-rama-temple-in-ayodhya)

Comment: Ayodha = A + Yuddha + ya = A place where there has never been fought a war. I'm not sure about any puranas tho.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, [Ayodhya Mahatmya of Skanda Purana](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc371729.html) goes into the glory of Ayodhya in detail.

> 59. Oh! Blessed indeed is your intellect, O ascetic, for you are enquiring about the glory of Ayodhyā.
> 60. The letter “A” indicates Brahman (Brahmā?); Viṣṇu is meant by the letter “YA”. The letter “DHA” is a form of Rudra. Thus shines the name
>     Ayodhyā.[8]
> 61. Since this city is not reached by all (major) sins like the murder of a Brāhmaṇa etc. along with minor sins, it (the city) is known as
>     Ayodhyā. (i.e. The city is beyond the pale of sins.)
> 62. O Brāhmaṇa, this is the first city of Viṣṇu. It does not touch the earth. This city that causes merit on the earth is stationed on
>     Sudarśana, the Discus of Viṣṇu.
> 63. By whom can the glory of this (city) be (adequately) described, O ascetic? It is here that Lord Viṣṇu himself dwells respectfully.

Answer (score 3):

Garud puran 16.144
Skanda puran 4.1.6.68
kāśīkāṃtī ca māyākhyā tvayodhyādvāravatyapi |
mathurāvaṃtikā caitāḥ sapta puryotra mokṣadāḥ || 68 ||
These seven cities are the bestowers of salvation here itself: Kāśī, Kāntī (Kāñcī), Māyā, Ayodhyā, Dvārāvatī, Mathurā and Avantikā.

Skanda puran 2.8.3.31
ṣaṣṭivarṣasahasrāṇi kāśīvāseṣu yatphalam |
tatphalaṃ nimiṣārddhena kalau dāśarathīṃ purīm || 31 ||
31. If in Kaliyuga anyone stays in the city of Rāma, the son of Daśaratha, even for (a period of) half a wink, he obtains that benefit which is obtained by staying at Kāśī for sixty thousand years.
Skanda puran 2.8.10.31-32
ṣaṣṭivarṣasahasrāṇi kāśīvāseṣu yatphalam |
tatphalaṃ nimiṣārddhena kalau dāśarathīṃ purīm || 31 ||
31. If Sarayū is seen, one obtains that merit which is obtained by means of stay in Avantī for thousands and crores of Kalpas.
32. By visiting the city of Daśaratha’s Son in Kaliyuga (even) for half a moment one obtains the merit of taking a holy plunge in Gangā for sixty thousand years.

Skanda puran 2.8 is Ayodhya mahatmya
Translation by G.V.Tagare 1950

Some Scholars claims Atharved Samhita 10.2.31-33 talks about Ayodhya